# Check if calling two function calls call the same function?

Tags: c++, c++20, template-meta-programming, introspection

I am implementing a generic `std::visit` for `std::variant` and I need to optimise for use cases like the following:

```
std::variant<Base, Derived1, Derived2> x;
std::visit([] (Base&) {/* code */}, x);
```

Here we go through dynamic dispatch even though the same function will be called regardless of the dynamic type of x!

Given an argument list and the name of an overloaded function / functor, how I can I check at compile time that the same functions will be called? I tried comparing function pointers, but that does not work...

Comment: Are you sure the compiler isn't smart enough to figure that out on its own?

Comment: *"the name of an overloaded function"*. that cannot be used except in MACRO.

Comment: For functor, in your case, `operator()` would be unique.

Comment: Even assuming you could figure it out, I'm not sure how you plan to avoid dynamic dispatch. There still needs to be a derived-to-base conversion in there somewhere; the actual type contained in `x` still matters.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, but if operator() is overloaded (for different arguments) I can’t check for equality...

Comment: @Igor Tandenik There will a derived to type conversion, and it might as simple as f(static_cast<Base&>(x.contained_union)) - no need for static dispatch here...

Comment: @SomeProgrammer: What do you mean by "static dispatch"? It's going to have an `if` statement either way. There is no way to cast whatever the stored type is to `Base&` *without* knowing what it is. That is, casting `x.contained_union` isn't going to work.

Comment: Cannot be solved in general case.  For some limited cases you can answer "Would an overload only ask for Base, or would some take derived", but only on restricted overload sets.  And it is obtuse enough and fragile I'd advise against it.  Make a type with a Derived operator and Base operator and detect ambiguity using SFINAE.  This does not work in every case, returns false positives and negatives.

Comment: What function pointers did you compare? There's a single operator() in the problem as stated.

Answer (score 0):

Given "the name of an overloaded function"... doesn't matter. You cannot call visit with the visitor being the name of an overloaded function.

Given a function object and multiple argument lists, identifying the functions selected by overload resolution to be invoked... is tricky.

Judging by the comments, it seems you want this particular case to optimize to `f(static_cast<Base&>(x.contained_union))`.

That is accessing the union through its member of that type, which may not be the active member. That requires not only the same function be selected by overload resolution, as you ask, but also the rules around active union members be followed. That is, you can only access a common initial sequence of standard layout types. So... the classes cannot be polymorphic, and Base cannot have any members or if it does, the derived classes cannot.

Thus, that optimization applies in fairly limited circumstances in standard C++.

But the typical visit for single variant visitation with a small number of types you'd want to write anyways is a simple switch. GCC compiles that optimally without any particular consideration of the inheritance: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/z1hhYEe64).